# FHIR Snapshot - Base selection

Tags: hl7-fhir

If an element in an SD has a type.profile, from where should the snapshot draw element descriptive information?

Given:

```
<StructureDefinition>
  ...
  <name value="Acme-Patient" />
  <baseDefininition value="http://hl7.org/fhir/StructureDefinition/Patient" />
  ...
  <differential>
    <element>
      <path value="identifier" />
      <type>
        <code value="Identifier" />
        <profile value="http://example.com/fhir/SD/id-qualified" />
  ...
</StructureDefinition>
```

HL7's Patient `http://hl7.org/fhir/StructureDefinition/Patient` has short:"An identifier for this patient" for Patient.identifier.

Example.com's id-qualified Identifier type has short: "An identifier qualified with a required system."

What should the Acme-Patient snapshot element for Patient.identifier have for its short value?

Before answering, consider that extensions are the more common use case here.  The type.profile defines the extension.  If from the baseDefinition, all extensions will have short "Additional Content defined by implementations".  However, in the above example, the type is much more generic than the base's short.

Comment: I think this should be raised as a change request as it's a space where the spec isn't sufficiently clear yet.

Comment: Ok...will be just a "needs clarification" as I don't know which is right!

Comment: I don't think we've agreed which is right - which is why it'll need committee discussion.